# How to include Boost in GNU Autotools project?

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, autotools

My project compiles using GNU autotools (`aclocal && autoconf && ./configure && make`).  I'd like to use Boost, and I'd like for other people to be able to compile it as well.

1. Should I put Boost in my project's dir, or rely on the system's Boost?
2. How should I tell autotools to use Boost? I've Googled and found many m4 files that claim to do this - but where should I put those m4 files? I can stash one in my `/usr/share/aclocal` dir, but that doesn't help someone else who wants to compile the project using `./configure && make`.

Answer (score 17):

[The Archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/The-Macros.html#The-Macros) has `AX_BOOST_*`.

I switched to [boost.m4](https://github.com/tsuna/boost.m4/wiki) for some time, but it is so painfully slow I could edit a Makefile with the full Boost path by hand in vim before boost.m4 finished testing for the second library.

I went back to the Archive and was happy to learn the boost macros are being actively maintained again; then I proceeded to purge boost.m4 from every one of my projects.

Relevant excerpts from a use case (assuming the ax_boost_*.m4 files are in subdir m4):

## ./bootstrap

```
aclocal -I m4 --install
...
```

## ./configure.ac

```
...
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
...
AX_BOOST_BASE([1.48],, [AC_MSG_ERROR([libfoo needs Boost, but it was not found in your system])])
AX_BOOST_SYSTEM
AX_BOOST_FILESYSTEM
...
```

## ./Makefile.am

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
EXTRA_DIST = bootstrap ...
SUBDIRS = ... src ...
...
```

## ./src/Makefile.am

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = \
    ... \
    $(BOOST_CPPFLAGS) \
    ...

...

AM_LDFLAGS = ... \
    $(BOOST_LDFLAGS)

...

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libFoo.la

...

libFoo_la_LIBADD = \
    ... \
    $(BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LIB) \
    $(BOOST_SYSTEM_LIB) \
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I just had issues with the comma in AC_MSG_ERROR `needs Boost, but it`, removing the comma solved it.

Comment: Then you're not quoting it properly (the `[` and `]` characters.)

Answer (score 2):

There's an excellent [boost.m4](https://github.com/tsuna/boost.m4/wiki) macro that you can include in your project in the `m4` subdirectory. These macros are located with `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])` in `configure.ac`.

Add `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4 --install` to the top-level `Makefile.am`, used by `automake`.

Here's why it's such a good macro:

```
BOOST_REQUIRE([1.54],[ACTION-IF-NOT-FOUND])
```

This will define `BOOST_CPPFLAGS` which you can add to `CPPFLAGS`, use in an `AC_SUBST`, etc.

For individual Boost components, it's possible to specify debug builds, static builds, etc. But the (typically) multi-threaded, dynamic libraries are best, e.g.,

```
BOOST_FILESYSTEM([mt])
```

will define `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LIBS` and `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LDFLAGS`. As another bonus, if the library relies on, say, Boost.System, then these library dependencies are automatically added to the `LIBS`, `LDFLAGS`, etc.

---

You should just specify that a Boost installation is required rather than trying to distribute it. It's easily built and installed from source, or from precompiled packages. The former takes a long time, but it's best to have an 'optimized' build on the system. There's a lot of software that can make use of a (robust and optimized) Boost implementation.

Then use the `BOOST_REQUIRE` error message if there's no acceptable version available.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd *definitely* rely on the system's Boost installation.  IIRC, the last time I built Boost it required non-standard tools (wrt the portable tools required for autoconf) for Boost to build.  It also took a long time.
2. `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR` is where those .m4 files go

   ```
   AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
   ```

where the macros are in the "m4" directory.  I'd expect the various Boost .m4 macros to have some way of telling `configure` what Boost package to look for (for multiple Boost installations) and where it is (nonstandard installations).

Comment: Thanks.  Can you give an example of how to use `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR` - I find AC perplexing. Also: If the user installs Boost as per the website's directions, will AC be able to find it? I'd like the error message to tell them what to do "Error: Boost is required.  Install as per directions on http://..."

Comment: The system's Boost might be outdated and/or incompatible, so you might have to install a different version in your home directory (when you don't have root access).

Comment: In that case, I'd probably look for a prebuilt version Boost that would work.  Failing that, you could possibly patch the source for the installed Boost version or download Boost from source and build it.

Comment: So you don't have root access on the machine, how will finding a prebuilt boost help in any way, if you are still using by default the system's boost? Downloading and building from source is exactly what I described, but you still have to make sure it's used instead of the system's.

Comment: Binary/source packages can usually be opened without installing them on the machine, so you get them in a directory, just as if they were built.  The AX_BOOST_BASE macro you mention (and I alluded to) can point to those directories by `configure --with-boost=/path/to/boost` etc.